# Detecting horizontal lines without Hough Transform

Tags: opencv, hough-transform, horizontal-line

I am working with Dalsa Nano camera mounted in a moving car (20 Km/H). The problem is that the shake of the module produce some fails frames (or it is produced by error in the memory buffer, we are working to know that). For the moment, I am working to fix this problem detecting the fail frames by image processing to discard them of the data base

The first method that I tested was detecting horizontal lines (0 grades) by Hough Transform and actually this method works well in many cases. The problem is that this method is too restrict. In the street will be highly probable to find horizontal lines (0 grades) in many cases like a buildings and this will produce false positive.

[image: case 1]

[image: case 2]

[image: case 3]

Can you help me with some suggestion to detect this fail frames with other methods?